# Getting several Traceback errors in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

New to Python.  Trying to understand how to import the pandas module.  I imported it through Pycharm, then ran a basic script seen below.  I get several errors that I'm not sure how to interpret

```
import pandas

x = input("Enter your age")
print(x)
```

I receive this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/leeb/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\leeb\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\leeb\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "C:\Users\leeb\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "C:\Users\leeb\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
  File "type.pxd", line 9, in init numpy.random.mtrand
ValueError: builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 440 from C header, got 432 from PyObject
```

Comment: `pandas` (or one of its dependencies) is installed incorrectly. You should uninstall and try re-installing using pip or conda

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your install.  You may need to update `pandas` and other packages that it depends on like `numpy`.

Comment: Error tracebacks include a lot of useful information. You should read up on how to interpret them. [Here's](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/) a place to start.

Comment: Thanks.  All very helpful.  In which directory should I install them?

Comment: @BradLee you should use a package manager which will handle where the install takes place. You can check if you have pip or conda using a terminal or the command prompt by typing in the command: `pip help` or `conda help`. Using a package manager can be very beneficial for keeping track of large complicated libraries like these ones.

Answer (score 1):

This error tends to happen when you have an older version of Numpy installed.

You should upgrade it, as follows:

`pip install numpy --upgrade`

If that doesn't work, try to use a specific version of numpy, as follows:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.15.1
```

Or, if you're using anaconda, try:

`conda update numpy`